# How to build bot GUI in slack.

Tags: bots, slack-api, slack

How to build bot GUI in slack. 
I have build a custom chat bot engine. 
It has rest endpoint where I post message and get response.

What I want is to integrate my chat bot engine with slack. So that I can use slack as my front end to post messages and get response. How to do this.

I have googled and I have got to many link like - slack web, slack integration, slack app. I am sure which one to follow.

Please let me know if there any steps I can follow to do this. 
Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad for this format. In general you need to build a Slack App to interface between you custom bot and Slack. But they are many different approaches on how you can do it. Check out the very good [documentation from Slack](https://api.slack.com/) to learn about how its done.